# Concatenate MySql results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query wich will search for some news and return the news data as its group, company and category. The thing is one news can have many companies and groups and i would need to concatenate this results (grupoNome and empresaNome) in one field each and so make this query return only one line:

This is my 'normal' query result:

```
id  titulo  categoriaId url     categoriaNome       grupoNome   empresaNome
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 1"   Company 1
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 1"   Company 2
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 1"   Company 3
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 1"   Company 4
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 2"   Company 1
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 2"   Company 2
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 2"   Company 3
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 2"   Company 4
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 3"   Company 1
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 3"   Company 2
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 3"   Company 3
5   Teste   1           teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 3"   Company 4
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT n.*, nc.nome AS categoriaNome, g.nome AS grupoNome, e.nome AS empresaNome FROM `noticias` n
INNER JOIN `noticiascategorias` nc ON n.categoriaId = nc.id
INNER JOIN `noticiasgrupos` ng ON n.id = ng.noticiaId
INNER JOIN `grupos` g ON g.id = ng.grupoId
INNER JOIN `noticiasempresas` ne ON n.id = ne.noticiaId
INNER JOIN `empresas` e ON e.id = ne.empresaId
WHERE n.url LIKE 'teste';
```

`noticiasgrupos`/`noticiasempresas` contains the news and the group/company many to many relantionship.

`grupos`/`empresas` contains the group/company info.

EDIT:

I Would need the results to be something like:

```
5   Teste   1   teste   "Todas as Notícas"  "Group 1_Group2_Group_3" "Company 1_Company_Company_3"
```

The divisor can be anything i can use to split later (| _ *)

Comment: What would you like the results to look like?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, forgot to explain this part

Comment: Bad idea: If you're going to be splitting later on, then DON'T CONCAT in the first place. If you insist on doing this, then look at [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for this, never heard of this function ! Why is it bad ? I'm gonna split it later with PHP to exhibit the names in the news page

Comment: group_concat has a length limit (1024 chars by default), so you might end up silently truncating your text. plus it's a waste of cycles - the equivalent of gift wrapping. looks pretty, but you're just going to rip it all off in a few minutes anyways.

Comment: @MarcB  I see what you mean, then what would be my best choice here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT to do this.  Just set your `GROUP BY` to whatever you would like to group on.  You can specify the sort order and separator for the GROUP_CONCAT also.

```
SELECT n.*, nc.nome AS categoriaNome, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.nome ORDER BY g.nome ASC SEPARATOR '_' ) AS grupoNome,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.nome ORDER BY g.nome ASC SEPARATOR '_' ) AS EmpresaNome
FROM `noticias` n
INNER JOIN `noticiascategorias` nc ON n.categoriaId = nc.id
INNER JOIN `noticiasgrupos` ng ON n.id = ng.noticiaId
INNER JOIN `grupos` g ON g.id = ng.grupoId
INNER JOIN `noticiasempresas` ne ON n.id = ne.noticiaId
INNER JOIN `empresas` e ON e.id = ne.empresaId
WHERE n.url LIKE 'teste'
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Comment: Great!  It looks like I can write queries in two different languages.  :)